# @PreDestroy methods of @ViewScoped CDI beans not called during Tomcat undeploy

Tags: jsf, cdi, omnifaces

I'm using CDI managed beans with `javax.inject.Named` and `org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped` annotations. One specific functionality in this bean will open a separate thread to continuously update a member field (if the user decides to activate it in the web interface).

This thread should be running as long as the user stays on the page (a PrimeFaces `poll` component will ensure that the view does not expire).

This thread should be stopped as soon as

- the user deactivates the functionality in the web interface (works)
- the user navigates to a different page (works)
- the web application is being undeployed by Tomcat (does not work)

I'm using the `@PreDestroy` method to stop the thread. My problem is that the `@PreDestroy` method is not invoked during a Tomcat undeploy and leads to memory leak warnings:

```
 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [webapp] appears to have started a thread named [pool-7-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Is this behavior expected? And if yes, what is the recommended way to clean up resources in CDI managed beans?

I'm running my web application with JDK8 and Tomcat 8.5 (CDI 1.2 / WELD 2.4.5, OmniFaces 2.6.8, JSF 2.2 / Mojarra 2.2.14).

Comment: Tried using the plain JSF CDI viewscoped instead of the omnifaces one? Same problem?

Comment: Yes, tried it first with the normal one, same problem (+ navigation clean-up does not work either).

Comment: Yes, the latter part is a known improvement in the Omnifaces one, but if the plain jsf one does not work either, it (effectively) is not related to omnifaces. Tried a sesssionscoped one (just for testing)? Tried an [mcve] in a full JavaEE server (TomEE, WildFly, Payara?)

Comment: Same problem with @SessionScoped (just tested it). I'm not sure when and if I find the time to test it in a full JavaEE server (never used them so far).

Comment: download one, install an deploy your war (make sure there is no jsf, cdi in your war)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to shut down my running threads via `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` and was storing the `ExecutorService` object as a transient member variable. The problem seems to have been that the serialization is done before calling the `@PreDestroy` method which caused the shutdown call to silently fail.

I got rid of the `@PreDestroy` method altogether and switched to a static member variable which I initialize once from `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()` and stop from `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()`.

Sorry for the false alarm!